moveit Robot does not stop after executing the planned movement
I´m currently working on the development of my own robot arm and have come across a problem. The Goal is to control the arm via motion planning in rviz and use realtime servo in the next step. The motion planning works as expected in simulation, but the real robot moves to the desired position and does not stop after reaching the goal. The arm wiggles around the goal. After the first motion planning execution rviz returns a success message, but the movement does not stop. After the secound execution, a timeout error accours.
I have tried to set a trajectory goal tolerance as the robot arm motors are not very preciesly. This attempt failed because I could not find out where to set the tolerances so that the parameters are used. Can anyone help me set the tolerances or perhaps has a different idea to solve the problem?
I´m using ROS2 Humble.
